# Pasar información de usuario a componente VUE usando Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy intentando pasar la información de usuario intentando hacerla llegar o reutilizar a un componente para poder hacer re utilización.

Me muestra el usuario logeado en json:

```
@auth
 <script>
 window.user = @json(auth()->user())
 </script>
@endauth
```

Gate.js

```
export default class Gate{

    constructor(user){
        this.user = user;
    }

    iduser(){
        return this.user;
    }

}
```

App.js

```
import Gate from './Gate.js';
Vue.prototype.$gate = new Gate(window.user);
```

puedo usarlo directamente en el template del componente algo así

```
<label>{{$gate.iduser()}}</label>
```

pero no puedo utilizarlo en el `script` del mismo componente, mi problema es como puedo usar eso para pasar a un model algo así ::

```
data(){
 return {
   idusuario: $gate.iduser // <<<< alguna otra opcion? esto no me funciona.
 }
}
```

Alguien sabe otro método de hacer llegar la información o correcciones a mi código. Saludos!

Comment: No se si laravel cambia algunas cosas.. pero en el hijo, deberia ser una prop, y deberias pasarle el valor al crear el componente en el padre...

Comment: pero el componente se ejecuta de forma dinámica, estoy tratando de hacer una caja negra donde se almacena esta información, para reutilizarla global sin tener que estarla pasando por cada componente.

Comment: AH ok.. no puedo ayudarte en ese caso, yo uso vuex para esas cosas.. laravel no lo soporta?

Comment: Solo para aclarar, esto no debería llevar paréntesis? `idusuario: $gate.iduser()`

Comment: Para utilizarlo en el componente debes usar this:
`data(){
 return {
   idusuario: this.$gate.iduser,
 }
}
`
De todas formas no entiendo la ventaja. Con laravel puedes pasar en una cookie la informacion del usuario y con vue-cookies obtenerla en app vue y almacenarla en el store con vuex ya que representa un estado de la aplicacion y reutilizarla en toda la aplicacion.

Comment: Una cosa mas, si todo el front esta hecho en vue te recomendaria utilizar jwt para autenticar al usuario con `tymondesigns/jwt-auth`.

Answer (score 0):

Como consejo, deberías evitar al máximo usar el objeto `window` fuera del `mount()`, porque en el caso de que estés haciendo render por servidor, no tienes el `window` hasta luego del `mount`, la variable `window` solo está disponible desde los browsers

Para estos casos puedes crear una variable global(sin usar el `window`) y luego usarlo en el data, por ejemplo:

```
@auth
 <script>
const global = this;
global.user = @json(auth()->user());
 </script>
@endauth
```

y luego en el data:

```
data(){
 return {
   idusuario: new Gate(global.user)
 }
}
```